# How to use an image on click to run JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, image, function, button, onclick

I'm attempting to use an image onClick to run a JavaScript function, instead of using a button onClick. I would like to know how I can use an image to make my JavaScript work.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<button onClick="philscode()"></button>
```

And when you click the button, it operates this JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var embedcodes = ["http://www.youtube.com/v/Cn75g5hhA"];

    function philscode()
 {
    var el =   document.getElementById("video0Embed");
        var clone=el.cloneNode(true);
        clone.setAttribute
        ('src', embedcodes [0]);
        el .parentNode.replaceChild(clone,el );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be exactly the same deal:
`<img onclick="philscode"/>`

Comment: Most if not all elements can accept the click event.

Comment: OK, but can anyone specify the code needed such as image source, or how can I move the image around?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/qw9L502n/